# Is there a way to force scrollbars in the desktop version of Ubuntu, like Netbook Remix does?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I'm not a particular fan of Ubuntu Netbook Remix, but the one feature I miss is the ability for a window taller than the vertical pixel length exists, it automatically adds a scrollbar.

Can I add this UI tweak to the standard version of Ubuntu? I can't see half of my Okay buttons in settings screens!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do what you are asking, however, you can use your "alt" key to move the window decorations past the top of the screen so you can see further down the window...

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> on your keyboard, left click and drag a window to see what I mean.

Comment: I suppose that will do. What I was asking for was a way to force the windows larger than the screen to have scrollbars, so there would never be a window that goes past the bottom of the screen.